# How to include files at the same level as the project pom in archetype-metadata.xml

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-archetype

I created a Maven custom archetype with the following structure:

[archetype-structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1R0xN.png)

When I create the project with the command `mvn archetype:generate` the **app.xml** and **app.properties** files are not included. How can I solve?